# Got a sass-loader error when I upgraded my dependencies from angular 2 to angular 5

Tags: angular, angular-cli

This is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "web-app",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "angular-cli": {},
  "scripts": {
    "start": "ng serve",
    "lint": "tslint \"src/**/*.ts\"",
    "test": "ng test",
    "pree2e": "webdriver-manager update",
    "e2e": "protractor"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "5.2.0", // from 2.0.2
    "@angular/compiler": "5.2.0", // from 2.0.2
    "@angular/core": "5.2.0", // from 2.0.2
    "@angular/forms": "5.2.0", // from 2.0.2
    "@angular/http": "5.2.0", // from 2.0.2
    "@angular/platform-browser": "5.2.0", // from 2.0.2
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "5.2.0", // from 2.0.2
    "@angular/router": "5.2.0", // from 3.0.0
    "angular2-google-maps": "0.16.0",
    "angular2-material-datepicker": "0.5.0",
    "core-js": "2.4.1",
    "js-marker-clusterer": "^1.0.0",
    "marker-clusterer-plus": "^2.1.4",
    "moment": "2.17.1",
    "ng2-inline-svg": "1.0.0",
    "rxjs": "5.5.6", // from 5.0.0-beta.12
    "ts-helpers": "1.1.1",
    "zone.js": "0.6.23"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.7.4", // added due to deprecated angular-cli
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "5.2.0", // added due to deprecated angular-cli
    "@angular/language-service": "5.2.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.8.3",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "4.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "2.8.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "4.2.1",
    "karma": "2.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "0.2.2",
    "protractor": "5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "4.1.0",
    "tslint": "5.9.1",
    "typescript": "2.5.3",
    "@types/googlemaps": "3.30.8", //from 3.26.10
    "@types/webpack": "2.2.8",
    "bower": "1.8.0",
    "karma-cli": "1.0.1",
    "karma-remap-istanbul": "0.2.1",
    "webpack": "2.1.0-beta.22"
  }
}
```

I tried to update some versions (as commented in the package.json file)
Most of my updates are to upgrade angular 2 to 5 and angular-cli to angular/cli

npm install is successful, but when I try to ng build I got this error:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/raw-loader!./node_modules/postcss-loader/lib??embedded!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js??ref--8-3!./src/styles.sass
Module build failed:
  color: rgba(79, 79, 79, 0.5)
                                ^
      Invalid CSS after "...79, 79, 0.5); }": expected 1 selector or at-rule, was "-ms-input-placehold"
      in C:\Users\user\Work\web\web-ang2\src\assets\styles\fragments\_input.sass (line 5, column 34)
ERROR in src/app/components/secure/business/contractor-search/contractor-search.component.spec.ts(27,7): error TS1005: ',' expected.
```

Maybe I upgraded some versions that are incompatible with each other.
How do resolve this?

Comment: have solved this error?

Answer (score 0):

For compatibility issues, I recommend:

1. delete your node_modules folder
2. `npm upgrade`
3. `npm update`

Although, your error code indicates that there are problems **in your custom files** `(\assets\styles\fragments\_input.sass`, and `contractor-search.component.spec.ts)` and not in the dependencies.

I strongly suggest you delete any whitespaces - did you move your code from a system with different localization settings? Or did you transform any of your files in any way? Might be just some random whitespaces which the framework try to parse. Or maybe just the cat walked trough the keyboard when you weren't looking? :P

Comment: Yes, for contractor-search.component.spec.ts. there is a missing ','. But for _input.sass, I am having trouble. It seems that when I build my app it does not understand sass files. even though I tried to use command **ng set defaults.styleExt sass**

Comment: what is your error message when the syntax is correct?

Comment: ERROR in ./node_modules/raw-loader!./node_modules/postcss-loader/lib??embedded!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js??ref--8-3!./src/styles.sass
Module build failed:
  color: rgba(79, 79, 79, 0.5)
                                ^
      Invalid CSS after "...79, 79, 0.5); }": expected 1 selector or at-rule, was "-ms-input-placehold"
      in C:\Users\user\Work\web\web-ang2\src\assets\styles\fragments\_input.sass (line 5, column 34)

Comment: maybe it still reads my sass files as css? even though my defaults.styleExt is already set as sass.

Comment: @kimondoe have you solved this error? i am getting same error while upgrading. can you give me some clue to fix it

Comment: it is what the error stated. I corrected my sass file to have the correct syntax.